# Using proxy class in Biztalk

Tags: .net, wcf, biztalk, proxy-classes

I've got a proxy class (created with WDSL).

Now i want to use this for developing a Biztalk Application.

How can i use the proxy class for sending and receiving messages. I know the process of configuring the ports with the proxy class. The only problem i've got is using the proxy class for my messages?

Comment: It would be useful to know which version of BizTalk you're using, and - more importantly - which adapter (i.e. SOAP or WCF), but I do think that thecolour covered the approaches for inline sends from an orchestration and using the WCF adpater, and I would generally prefer the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to call a web service from Biztalk? If so you can either

1. Generate your proxy class and then use this from in .Net class library called from an orchestration
2. Use Biztalk's Consume Service wizard to generate the schemas, orchestrations amd run-time bindings needed to call the service.

If you want to go the first route, create a class library which makes the web service call by exposing a method which can be called by your orchestration. If you need to pass Biztalk messages as arguments to the method use the XLANGMessage type found in Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes library. You will first need to generate a .net representation of your message schema (using xsd.exe or svcutil.exe) so that you can deserialise the message using XLANGPart.RetrieveAs(typeOf(xxx)). If you need to pass the web service response out into another message then you can make your .net method return type XmlDocument and as long as the response maps to a message schema, BizTalk will take care of the conversion for you.

If you want to go the second route, then it's generally easier because BizTalk will generate all the artifacts you need to make a call to the service without any coding needed. This is the best approach if you don't have to do anything fancy like change the web service endpoint address at runtime.

Hope this helps.
TC

Comment: I'd definitely recommend the second route. If you use the wizard to consume the service and generate a WCF-Custom port, then you can really get in there and customize all of the WCF settings that you might want, using the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in an orchestration scenario, a web service is consumed by adding a web reference to the project (of course we can do it without to as well)  and linking send and receive shapes to the operation port (web method)  it means, a proxy class is being generated for us allowing to consume the WS.

References: [http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2007/01/31/Calling-Web-Service-from-BizTalk-2006-in-a-Messaging-only-Scenario-(aka-Content-based-Routing).aspx](http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2007/01/31/Calling-Web-Service-from-BizTalk-2006-in-a-Messaging-only-Scenario-%28aka-Content-based-Routing%29.aspx)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amantaras/archive/2010/03/03/consuming-a-web-service-in-a-non-orchestration-scenario.aspx